# Java TreeMap iterator not working correctly for String keys

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I have a TreeMap that maps String keys to a custom City class.  Here is how it is instantiated:

```
TreeMap<String, City> nameDictionary = new TreeMap<String, City>(new CityNameComparator());
```

CityNameComparator implementation:

```
    public class CityNameComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare (String c1, String c2) {
        return c1.compareTo(c2);
    }
}
```

I have a method that returns an iterator that should iterate through the map in key-ascii order:

```
    public Iterator<City> getNameIterator(){
    return nameDictionary.values().iterator();
}
```

For some reason the values are returned in the order they were added to the TreeMap.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post working code that replicates the problem? I don't see any obvious errors, though having a custom comparater that just uses the natural ordering of String anyway is kinda pointless.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work.  It's always worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class test2 {

    public static class City {
        public final String m_name;

        public City(String aName) {
            m_name = aName;
        }
    }

    public static class CityNameComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        public int compare (String c1, String c2) {
            return c1.compareTo(c2);
        }
    }

    public static class CityMap {
        TreeMap<String, City> nameDictionary = new TreeMap<String, City>(new CityNameComparator());

        public Iterator<City> getNameIterator(){
            return nameDictionary.values().iterator();
        }

        public City put(String aName) {
            return nameDictionary.put(aName, new City(aName));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CityMap cityMap = new CityMap();
        cityMap.put("d");
        cityMap.put("b");
        cityMap.put("c");
        cityMap.put("a");

        for (Iterator<City> cities = cityMap.getNameIterator(); cities.hasNext(); ) {
            City city = cities.next();
            System.out.println(city.m_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

a

b

c

d

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a `LinkedHashMap` hasn't been assigned to the `Map` reference by mistake? That would preserve the order the entries were added to the map.

Or perhaps there is a bug in the code that is adding entries, putting the wrong value with a key.

Iterate over the entries, and see what is in the map:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, City> e : dictionary.entrySet()) 
  System.out.println(e.getKey() + " --> " + e.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, stupid bug.  I was assigning a different iterator based on a bug somewhere else.  It works fine now.